# Windows Phone 7 - Custom Tile support

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, live-tile

I'm looking to create an app that has a secondary tile that when pressed, runs some code and then exits out to the start screen, much like 'Stop The Music!' where you can pin a quick-stop tile to tap and instantly stop any audio media playing. I am certain this works on WP8 applications as the feature works perfectly on my Lumia 820 however I am unsure if there is a way to do it for WP7 and I am also struggling to find any tutorials/papers explaining how it works or how to do it.

The tile won't be a live tile feeding back information but rather a short cut to a feature in the app, can anyone point me towards a clear explanation/tutorial or explain themselves please?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code:

```
StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData
    {
        Title = "Secondary Tile",
        BackgroundImage = new Uri("/image.png", UriKind.Relative),
        Count = 5,
        BackTitle = "Secondary Tile",
        BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
        BackContent = "Secondary tile sample"
    };

    // having a unique NavigationUri is necessary for distinguishing this tile
    string tileUri = "/MainPage.xaml?id=1";
    ShellTile.Create(new Uri(tileUri, UriKind.Relative), tileData);
```

Note that you can only create a secondary tile in reaction to a user event.

Comment: Ah great, just to clarify, when I create the page for the code to run on do I use the normal portrait page, or would some other kind of page/class be much better suited if I don't want to show anything other that a push notification?

Comment: You can create whatever page you want, the only limitation is that creating the live tile should be in reaction to a user action. For just showing a notification I would show a blank page with a MessageBox, but it all depends on your specific app. BTW: if the answer has helped you, please accept / up vote it.

Comment: Thanks! Yet to test the code, will flag it as the answer as soon as I test it :)